# Item in object has two value need the second value jquery

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object that has two value "384-768" how can I get the second value for all of the Items. if the item has two value get the highest one if its only one return that one only. how do I get that from the object?

Comment: Add some code snipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get second value using `split` (it splits strings to array by separating the string with passed argument)

```
"384-768".split('-')[1]
```

and find in loop maximal element (after converting to integer with `parseInt`)